# Oracle ORA-00936 Missing Expression Error with Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g, crystal-reports

I have a working query that connects to a remote Oracle database through the Oracle 11g Client.  To incorporate a parameter based on an alias I used this query as a subquery with the parameter in the main query.  I don't see anything the matter - though something obviously is - so before I grind on this for another hour I thought I would pose the code to the experts:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
  SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "UNITS"."ModelYear", "UNITS"."Make", "UNITS"."Model", "UNITS"."Class3", 
    "UNITS"."Class3Description", "UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) AS "FSC",
    "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment", "UNITS"."UnitStatus",
    CASE WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '1' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'F' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '10' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '15') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'U' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '11' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'D' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '2' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '8' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '18') AND 
    SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'C' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '3' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '9' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '17') AND 
    SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'B' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '16' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'S' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '13' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '4') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'L' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '12' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '14') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'G' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '19' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '20') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'R' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '5' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'E' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '6' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'H' THEN 'Y'
      ELSE ''
      END AS "MISMATCH"
  FROM "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS"
  WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580' AND "UNITS"."UnitStatus"='A'
  ) "U"
WHERE  "U"."MISMATCH" = {?Mismatch}
ORDER BY "U"."UnitNumber"
```

When I attempt to run this query I recieve a "Failed to retrieve date from the database" error, ORA-00936: missing expression.

For the life of me I can't see what the problem is.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What is this:  {?Mismatch}

Comment: That prompts Crystal Reports 13 to ask for a parameter.  In this case the absence of a value would return all records, while "Y" would only return those records where the MISMATCH alias = "Y".

Comment: Then maybe you should have tagged with CR also?  What if you run the query right from sql?  Remove query components until problem goes away, then add back one at a time.  That is what anyone else would have to do.  Since you do not provide the table definitions, it is not like someone can run this query to see how to fix it.

Comment: I added the CR tag as you suggested.  •  I don't have any means of running the query directly due to administrative restrictions on my system, so all I can do is iteratively attempt to run it in CR and adjust based on feedback.   •  As for removing query components, there isn't much to remove since I know the entire subquery runs without issue.  The problem lay in the first 3 or last two lines.

Comment: Why are all the column names string literals? Is this how oracle works? Seems very sloppy and it's difficult to read and write.

Comment: I don't administer the database, so I can't change the way the query looks.  Double quotes are either aliases or table/column names; single quotes are the literals.  It is sloppy, I agree...but without them no joy.  But aside from that, any idea why the query isn't working?

Comment: Where are you using this query in CR...is error thrown by CR or firing query directly on database

Comment: The query is inserted into a Command in the Database Expert.  The error is thrown by CR after the parameter is entry closes.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are complicating the process...to my experience `Select *` format doesnt work in crystal

If your requirement  is to use sub query then instead of `*` take column  names like select u.unitnumber ...... From (sub query) and use in Crystal Reports

Edit:-----------------------------------------------------------------
One option is not to use the `*` and use column names as shown in below query.

```
SELECT U.UnitNumber,U.ModelYear,U."Make", U."Model", U."Class3", 
    U."Class3Description", U."TechnicalSpecification", U."FSC",
    U."OwnerDepartment", U."UnitStatus", U.MISMATCH 
    FROM(
SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "UNITS"."ModelYear", "UNITS"."Make", "UNITS"."Model", "UNITS"."Class3", 
    "UNITS"."Class3Description", "UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) AS "FSC",
    "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment", "UNITS"."UnitStatus",
    CASE
    WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '1' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'F' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '10' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '15') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'U' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '11' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'D' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '2' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '8' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '18') AND 
    SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'C' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '3' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '9' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '17') AND 
    SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'B' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '16' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'S' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '13' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '4') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'L' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '12' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '14') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'G' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN ("UNITS"."Class3" = '19' OR "UNITS"."Class3" = '20') AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'R' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '5' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'E' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN "UNITS"."Class3" = '6' AND SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) <> 'H' THEN 'Y'
      ELSE ''
      END AS "MISMATCH"
  FROM "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS"
  WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580' AND "UNITS"."UnitStatus"='A') U
  WHERE  "U"."MISMATCH" = {?Mismatch}
ORDER BY "U"."UnitNumber"
```

Second Option:

May be complexity of the query is making it impossible to trace the error... So you can do other way around take simple query in `add command` rest of the checking you can do in crystal reports locally which will be easy to develop and also trace the errors.

Try below solution and let me know your input.

Use this command and create the `MisMatch` internally in the report itself.

Query:

```
SELECT "UNITS"."UnitNumber", "UNITS"."ModelYear", "UNITS"."Make", "UNITS"."Model", "UNITS"."Class3", 
    "UNITS"."Class3Description", "UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", SUBSTR("UNITS"."TechnicalSpecification", 13, 1) AS "FSC",
    "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment", "UNITS"."UnitStatus",
    FROM "MFIVE"."VIEW_ALL_UNITS" "UNITS"
  WHERE  "UNITS"."OwnerDepartment" LIKE '580' AND "UNITS"."UnitStatus"='A'
```

Place required columns in report design and create a formula `MisMatch` and write below code and place it on design.

@Mismatch formula

```
    if   Class3  = '1' AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'F' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '10' OR   Class3  = '15') AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'U' THEN 'Y'
else if   Class3  = '11' AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'D' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '2' OR   Class3  = '8' OR   Class3  = '18') AND
SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'C' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '3' OR   Class3  = '9' OR   Class3  = '17') AND
SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'B' THEN 'Y'
else if   Class3  = '16' AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'S' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '13' OR   Class3  = '4') AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'L' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '12' OR   Class3  = '14') AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'G' THEN 'Y'
else if (  Class3  = '19' OR   Class3  = '20') AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'R' THEN 'Y'
else if   Class3  = '5' AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'E' THEN 'Y'
else if   Class3  = '6' AND SUBSTR(  FSC , 13, 1) <> 'H' THEN 'Y'
ELSE ''
```

Now create parameter mismatch and I assume your parameter will have either `y` or `N` and use this paramter to supress the data in report.

Go to section expert of the design write below code for supress.

```
if {?Mismatch}='Y'
then true
else false
```

Try and let me know the result

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but it throws the same error.  I used the subquery because the alias "MISMATCH" has to be calculated for all rows before the {?Mismatch} parameter can be evaluated.  I employed the exact same process just yesterday on another query, so I'm at a loss to figure out what is leaving a bad taste in CR's mouth.

Comment: In main query have you used column names instead of star? If not check that way

Comment: I replaced the asterisk with the column names as you suggested.  It still throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't answer why a correctly-formatted parameter produces a "missing expression" error, the approach Siva suggests does work.  Extra-credit to Siva for effort!

I did attempt a few other changes, most notably ensuring the parameter name and the column name were different.  Still returns the same error message.

For my purposes I will have to hard-code the parameter value in the WHERE clause for my purposes and run separate reports if I need to see all rows or only rows where MISMATCH = "Y".  Far from ideal, but it works.